# How can I convert string format from "YYYYMMDD" to "YYYY-MM-DD" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have to convert string format accordance with title on the top, for example from 20200101 to 2020-01-01, but the format keep up string, no change becomes date format. How can I do that? Help me please, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let date = 2020

```js
let date = "20200219"

let year = date.substring(0, 4);
let month = date.substring(4, 6);
let day = date.substring(6, 8);

let newDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`

console.log({newDate})
```